# How to pass argument name as a parameter?

Tags: python, django

I have this code:

```
hobbies2 = form.cleaned_data.pop('hobbies2')
PersonneHobby.objects.filter(personne=obj).delete()
for pk_str in hobbies2:
    try:
        hobby = TagTraduit.objects.get(pk=int(pk_str))
        p = PersonneHobby.objects.create(personne=obj,
                                         hobby=hobby)
        p.save()
    except ValueError:
        break  # hack in the POST
    except LookupError:
        break  # hack in the POST
```

I will have the same code for 4 different fields, exemple with `programme`:

```
programmes2 = form.cleaned_data.pop('programmes2')
PersonneProgramme.objects.filter(personne=obj).delete()
for pk_str in programmes2:
    try:
        programme2 = TagTraduit.objects.get(pk=int(pk_str))
        p = PersonneProgramme.objects.create(personne=obj,
                                             programme=programme2)
        p.save()
    except ValueError:
        break  # hack = tout stopper
    except LookupError:
        break  # hack = tout stopper
```

Exactly the same code, only name of the field change. So I'd like to make a generic function and call it like this:

```
def update_field(post_field, class_field, **kwargs):
    try:
        values = form.cleaned_data.pop(post_field)
        class_field.objects.filter(personne=obj).delete()
        for pk_str in values:
            try:
                v = TagTraduit.objects.get(pk=int(pk_str))
                p = class_field.objects.create(**{'personne': obj,
                                                  field_name: v})
                p.save()
            except ValueError:
                break  # hack = tout stopper
            except LookupError:
                break  # hack = tout stopper
    except KeyError:
        pass
update_field('programmes2', PersonneProgramme, 'programme')
update_field('hobbies2', PersonneHobby, 'hobby')
```

My main problem is the last parameter, which is the name of the field to use when creating the record in the database.

How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it with an arbitary number of keyword-arguments (`**`) and insert calculated additional parameters inside the function:

```
def update_field(field, update_this, **kwargs):
     ...
     kwargs[update_this] = TagTraduit.objects.get(pk=int(pk_str))
     p = field.objects.create(**kwargs)
     ...
```

this allows you to call it like that:

```
update_field(PersonneHobby, 'hobby', personne=obj)
update_field(PersonneProgramme, 'programme', personne=obj)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
def update_field(..., field_name):
   ...
   tag = TagTraduit.objects.get(pk=int(pk_str))
   p = PersonneProgramme.objects.create(**{'personne': obj, field_name: tag})
```

Comment: I've updated my question, using kwargs, you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

I will go with what @MSeifert said. If you want whatever you have written to work, I mean with positional arguments alone.

```
def f(a,b,c):
    a.func(b=b, c=c)  # this is perfectly legal
```

But the better way to go about it is,

```
def f(a, **kwargs):
    a.func(**kwargs)  # kwargs is passed as a dict. **kwargs is
                      # unpacking it into key1=val1, key2=val2, ...
```

Comment: I've updated my question, using kwargs, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Sayse You could say that if you hate my guts for some reason. And no. It is more. Look at the first block. He was not sure about collecting `c` from `(a,b,c)` as `(...,c=c)`

Comment: What? I don't hate anyone really, let alone strangers on a website. I was pointing out that you've just shown a snippet of code (that wouldn't work) and then stated that someone elses answer is the right way to go, which is unnecessary and an upvote to said answer would be much more productive.

Comment: The first one, `b` and `c` are both values, so they won't have the same value as the name of the keyword that should hold that value.

Comment: @Sayse Well you are **wrong**. `b` and `c` are not values at all, they are names / identifiers. So `a.func(b=b,c=c)` is legal and it stands for `a.func(a=<object with name a>, b=<object with name b>)`. Python variables are not the same as C variables. In C, C++ you couldn't do it. Calling them "names" is more appropriate.