# filter the table by a search query with search fields is in a dictionary

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a dictionary & a string value like:

```
d=  {"check-in": "12-04-2016", "check-out": "13-04-2016", "location": "India"}

value = 'india'
search = d['check-in']
```

Here I am reading the keys which are a column name in my DB table.

Note: Here everything is dynamic that means value of columns are dynamically set.

I want to query with multiple filter in django such a way that i ll get all details set by dictionary(d). That means i want to filter by multiple column values.

Query i wrote:

```
modelInstance.objects.filter(search = value).
```

Here i am getting error.

If someone don't understand please tell i ll explain more

Here i a storing the column name in a string like:

```
 field = "check-in"
```

looping a for loop to get all the column name

Error:

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'field' into field
```

Comment: `Here i am getting error.` Post the error report.

Comment: Wild stab in the dark but it appears to be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36452760/1324033), applying filters set in a dictionary

Comment: Look like you need to implement a search engine over your database. Have a look at http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.4.1/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `**` ([unpacking argument](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)) to expand dictionary into keyword arguments.

Before doing that, you need to convert query keys to field names, for example `check-in` to `check_in_date` (assuming actual field name in `check_in_date`)

```
query_to_field_mapping = {
    'check-in': 'check_in_date',
    'check-out': 'check_out_date',
    'location': 'location',
}

d = {"check-in": "12-04-2016", "check-out": "13-04-2016", "location": "India"}
query = {query_to_field_mapping[key]: value for key, value in d.items()}
objects = Model.objects.filter(**query)
```

Comment: What is the importance of query_to_field_mapping  here?

Comment: @danny, `check-in` cannot be a field name, right? So `query_to_field_mapping` is there to map `check-in` to `check_in_date` (imaginary real field name)

Comment: Ok got it. But if you can tell me if i am storing the actual field name in variable & then trying to filter then what should i do then that ll be more apreciated?

Comment: @danny, Then, replace the last three lines with `objects = Model.objects.filter(**d)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from django.db.models import Q

value = 'india'
search = 'check-in'
filter = {
    'check-in': Q(model_check-in__eq=value),
    'check-out': Q(model_check-out__eq=value),
    'location': Q(model_location__eq=value)
}


return Model.objects.filter(filter[search])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary in filter.

```
d=  {"check-in": "12-04-2016", "check-out": "13-04-2016", "location": "India"}

modelInstance.objects.filter(**d)
```